# Probability of leak occurring

Tags: probability, statistics

> A waste disposal company averages 6:5 spills of toxic waste per month. Assume spills occur
>   randomly at a uniform rate, and independently of each other, with a negligible chance of 2 or
>   more occurring at the same time. Find the probability there are 4 or more spills in a 2 month
>   period

The way I read this, let $X = \{\text{Number of spills in 2 month period}\}$

We want $P(X \ge 4)$.

But I am confused and dont know how to proceed?

Comment: What does $6:5$ mean in this context?  Beyond that, I'd say it sounds like a good situation in which to use a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the rate of spills per month is *6.5.* Then you might
model spills over a two-month period as $Y \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_2 = 13).$
With that model, you seek $P(Y \ge 4) = 1 - P(Y \le 3).$

You can find this probability using
a calculator and the PDF for a Poisson distribution or using software.
I got an answer very near one, which makes sense since the average
number of spills in two months is $E(Y) = \lambda_2 = 13.$

The sketch below shows the PDF of $Y.$ You want the probability represented
by the bars to the right of the vertical dotted line.

[image]

Comment: Still there? Can you find $P(Y=0) = e^{-13}, P(Y=1), P(Y=2),$ and $P(Y=3)?$ Back in several hours.